# How do i reset my frozen phone without losing all my data

Tags: factory-reset, data-recovery

My Lg g4 shut off on me and won't turn on. It freezes on the lg screen. I know i can reset it but i have over 1000 pictures that weren't backed up and i cant afford to lose them. The past year of my life is on the phone.I need a way to turn on my phone without losing everything. There has to be a way

Answer (score 0):

Well, unfortunately you can't really recover your photos. If they were on a SD card it would be a lot more easier but it seems like the photos are in the internal storage.

There is still 1 thing you can try:

Your recovery! Find a way to boot your phone into the recovery. I assume your phone is still startable (not bootable). In most recoveries is an option for browsing the storage. If that's the case you just need to copy your photos to an external storage.

But what if your recovery doesn't support such a feature?
But you must have tried the first option first because this option is more risky:

1. Download TWRP (twrp.me) <- You will love that thing ;D (**EDIT**: This will only work if your bootloader is unlocked!!!)
2. Copy the TWRP zip to your external storage
3. Boot in your recovery and flash the zip
4. Reboot into your recovery (should be TWRP now) and now I believe there is a way to open the doors to your internal storage for your computer. Otherwise there is an option for browsing your phones internal storage (on the phone)
5. Last step! Copy the whole thing over there ;D

Hope I helped ya! ;D

Comment: TWRP was my first thought, too. Only drawback here: If the device's boot loader wasn't already unlocked, OP won't be able to flash or even boot (e.g. via `fastboot boot twrp.img`). And unlocking the bootloader usually implies a factory reset – which makes this a hen-and-egg thing.

Comment: @Izzi right but there might be an locked-bootloader-recovery out there (maybe?) on XDA like that one for Sony. I'll do some research

Comment: I doubt that. It's the device that rejects write attempts to the recovery partition if the bootloader is locked, nothing much the recovery-devs can do about that.